# Removing xlab in residual graph plot(fit, which = 1)

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to get rid of xlab in residual plot. It is not possible to set xlab = "". How to do it?

Sample code:

```
x<-rnorm(20,2)
y<- x + rnorm(20,1)
fit<- lm(y~x)
plot(fit, which = 1:1)
```

In that graph are two lines of xlab:

Fitted values 
 
lm(y ~ x)

How can I remove lm(y ~ x)? I tried to set

```
fit$call = ""
```

but without success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
 plot(fit, which=1, sub.caption="")
```